# how to do i check whether the association is vaild or not on rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

```
 =>s = User.new
 => #<User id: nil, first_name: nil, last_name: nil, email: nil, address: nil, type_of_user: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> 
2.2.0 :015 > o.publisher_id = s
 => #<User id: nil, first_name: nil, last_name: nil, email: nil, address: nil, type_of_user: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> 
2.2.0 :016 > o.publisher_id = 6
 => 6 
2.2.0 :017 > s = User.create(:first_name => "Bostnss")
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
 => #<User id: nil, first_name: "Bostnss", last_name: nil, email: nil, address: nil, type_of_user: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> 
2.2.0 :018 > o.publisher_id = 5
```

Comment: i was applying it i can find the way to check whether it is correct or not

Comment: ```s.valid?``` might help here

Answer (score -1, accepted):

for that you have to first know that what are the associations that are you using for that you have to apply this 
code 
in my app i have three models user , order and articles

so for checking the associations i use this

a = Article.new
after insert the data and

use command

a.realod

after that

a.user [the name that i given in the association ]
if it works that means that associations works